Using procmail to pipe to a php script, can I add a variable to be checked
I have a procmail script set up which pipes to a PHP script when an email subject line matches:
:0
* ^To.info@domain.com|^Subject.*(REMOVE|Undelivered Mail)
| /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/somefolder/script.php

Is there a way to pass a parameter to the PHP script via the procmail command, like you do with query-string parameters? I've tried the following, and neither works:
| /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/somefolder/script.php?iscron=1
| /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/somefolder/script.php --iscron=1

I want the PHP script to be able to check what is triggering it. Thanks for any help.

This is rather unclear; are you asking how to distinguish which part of the Procmail regex matched (which my answer attempts to solve) or how to parse arguments in PHP (which I imagine must be thorougly answered by existing questions)? Please [edit] to clarify.

I edited a bit, hope that made it clearer.  @ken-lee answered the question, so I'll mark that as the answer. Thanks.

Does this answer your question? PHP, pass parameters from command line to a PHP script

@triplee, I searched and didn't find that, probably because I was looking for something procmail related. I think it's good to have this question posted as well, for someone looking for the same thing.

In PHP, to get the value(s) of parameter(s) passed from the command line, you may parse the $argv
For further details, one may see official documentation
So assuming that your command (to pipe from procmail to the PHP) is:
/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/somefolder/script.php iscron=1 subject=stackoverflow

The script.php can be:
<?php

unset($argv[0]);
parse_str(implode('&',$argv),$_REQUEST);

if ($_REQUEST["iscron"]=="1") {
  // do things for iscron=1
}else{
  // do other things
}

// $_REQUEST["subject"] will be "stackoverflow"

?>


thanks. The answer I needed was just the adding of  iscron=1 to the pipe command. The parsing example helps too.
